# Why can't PHP flock on btrfs filesystem?

Tags: php, laravel, containers, chromebook, btrfs

I am trying to set up a chromebook for Laravel development and I was having trouble with my project throwing "419 Page Expired" on every form.  The project works fine on a Manjaro development machine.

I traced the issue down to Laravel's file-system session driver not retrieving the session token from the file system.

It seems that Crostini (ChromeBook Linux Container) uses a btrfs root filesystem and any attempt to use php's "flock" function always results in a failure response.

Has anyone come across this before? Does anyone have any idea of a possible work-around? I would imagine, with the abundance of containerised development environments, that this is a common problem, but I have googled to no avail.

Comment: 419 error code means usually that you don't have CSRF protection, you can disable it, or see more here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf

Comment: @VincentDecaux thanks for taking the time to point that out.  I am fully aware of what the 419 means, and I managed to chase the error through the laravel source code to a problem with the Session driver that prevented it from loading the correct token (please re-read the question).  Disabling CSRF protection is not an option, I need to be able to develop applications that utilize it.  It also won't fix the issue for other parts of the framework that rely on flock.